# Clone a record and all it's related records in Entity Framework CORE

Tags: entity-framework-core

I've got a Person model which has a 1:Many relationship to address, i.e. one Person record can have many linked Address records.

PersonModel (truncated)

```
public class PersonModel : RootModel {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
```

AddressModel (truncated)

```
public class ContactAddressModel : RootModel {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AddressID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonID")]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual PersonModel objHuman { get; set; }
```

This all works fine and dandy for retrieving, saving, viewing, etc.

I now need to take a snapshot of the Person record and it's associated Address record(s).

I can duplicate the Person record easily enough using

```
    PersonModel objRecordPerson = await _context.Persons
        .Include(p => p.AddressIDs)
       . AsNoTracking()
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PersonID == PersonID);

    PersonModel objSnapshot = objRecordPerson;
    objSnapshot.PersonID = 0;
    _context.Persons.Add(objSnapshot);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Is there a handy-dandy way of also duplicating any related records in EF CORE or is the only option duplicating the Person record, then iterating through the  collection of related Address records, adding the Address duplicating one-at-a-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `.Add`ing the snapshotted record, iterating through the `AddressIDs` and setting the primary key (`AddressID` in this case) to 0 creates a new `Address` record which takes the new `PersonID` from the snapshotted record.

```
 PersonModel objSnapshot = objRecordPerson;
 objSnapshot.PersonID = 0;
 _context.Persons.Add(objSnapshot);
 foreach (var item in objSnapshot.AddressIDs) {
     item.AddressID = 0;
 }
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```